# Using NER to extract airport codes and airline codes using any NLP library?

Tags: nlp, nltk, apache-spark, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I would like to extract Airport Codes & Airline Codes from a string. Airport/City Codes are 3  letter alpha codes. Airline Codes are 2 letter alpha & alpha numeric codes.

Example for airline codes

AA == American Airlines.

Airport codes

JFK == John F. Kennedy International Airport

LGA == LaGuardia Airport

I have a list of all the airport codes and airline codes in the world.
the type of string that i want to extract is like.

JFKAAX/BOSAACHIM100.00Q9USMEXQ125.00YLEE/CH30500.00ENDROE0.56893458

there is an ambiguity  because  KAA can also be identifed as an airport. Which is a valid airport code.

How can i use NER to extract the two items. If NER is not suitable is there any other way.

Comment: is there a fixed pattern for the airport codes? could you put up a list of sample strings? what is the source of these codes?

Comment: @alvas yes there is a fixed pattern.  
AirportCode AirlineCode AirportCode.  
OriginCity Airline DestinationCity.  
sometimes there are decimal numbers between AirportCode &   AirlineCode or "X/".  
I was wondering if i train a model( or create a corpora/corpus) with all the AirlineCodes & CityCodes 
will NLTK or OpenNLP be able to extract the AirlineCodes & AirportCodes and their position. 
NER does this type of work right ?? extract Location Name (Airport Code) Oganization Name (Airline Code)

Comment: @Harsh.Scindia I think, that NER is not suitable for you problem. I'd use simple string operations and regex.

Answer (score 2):

I used simple regex, tell if it is ok:

```
In [1]: a = 'JFKAAX/BOSAACHIM100.00Q9USMEXQ125.00YLEE/CH30500.00ENDROE0.56893458'
In [4]: import re
In [15]: re.findall('(\w{3})(\d*(\.\d*)?)(\w{2})', a)
Out[15]: 
[('JFK', '', '', 'AA'),
 ('BOS', '', '', 'AA'),
 ('CHI', '', '', 'M1'),
 ('00Q', '9', '', 'US'),
 ('MEX', '', '', 'Q1'),
 ('00Y', '', '', 'LE'),
 ('CH3', '0500.00', '.00', 'EN'),
 ('DRO', '', '', 'E0'),
 ('568', '934', '', '58')]
```

Could you provide what should be output for string which you posted? You can mark airport names, and air line with brackets e.g.:
X